# apk file not installed in android mobile

Tags: cordova

**INTEL XDK File not installed in android mobile**
I'm using new version 3522 for Intel XDK. Basically i'm developed sample project just through alert message for Button click event in javascript but total 'APK' file size is too large(24.6Mb) file. Same code i'm run and build Phonegap that created APK that file size only 700Kb. Then Intel XDK APK file not supported any android mobile without XWalkCoreLibrary app Installed but Phonegap APK is supported any android mobile

Answer (score 0):

The Intel XDK is file is large because it's using crosswalk. It is a browser embarqued in the app.

Intel XDK docs says that you can remove it.

On Projet tabs, in Build settings, Android, you can unselect "Optimize with Crosswalk".

Be aware that by removing it, the compatibility with Android device < 4.4 could be impacted. Since the webview for rendering the app will be the Android one that can not be updated and is very old. You could have some rendering and performance issue without it.

More infos here :

https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/using-the-crosswalk-for-android-build-option